# Defining A Function Pointer Using Assignment In c

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm learning C. I know what the first line is doing; it's making a pointer to a function with no arguments and it returns an int. But wtf is the second doing?

My guess is that it is casting an int into a function? But what does it mean to turn an int into a function?
Also, why does it cause an error when I try to call the function: 'function()'?

```
int (*function) ();
function = (int (*) ()) (1000);
```

Comment: Your understanding of the first line is incorrect.  That line defines a variable which is a pointer to a function that takes an undetermined number of arguments.  If you want a function that takes no arguments, you want `int (*function)(void);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall, the code is nonsense. Where did you get it from?

> it's making a pointer to a function with no arguments

Rather, it is making a pointer to a function with obsolete style parameter list.

> But wtf is the second doing?

It assigns the function pointer to point at address 1000 (decimal), my means of a cast from int to the function pointer type.

> why does it cause an error when I try to call the function: 'function()'?

Likely because there is no such function allocated at address 1000. You might not even have access to that area etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question so clearly! Usually, my question gets deleted by other people for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

learning function pointer is pain in ass.
simple example maybe help for better understand.

suppose you want point to this function:

```
int sum (int a , int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

so you need define a pointer with same type:

```
int *pointerToSum (int, int);
```

and simply assign it to function:

```
pointerToSum = &sum;
```

if you want use it:

```
(*pointerToSum)(3, 5); //8
```

you can use `function-pointer` tag to find out more complex answers.

your question delete by people because there is duplicate question asked before.

I implement function-pointer for myself and it's a little complex and you can see in : [exercise of function pointer](https://github.com/mostafaoraei/Piscine_cpp/tree/main/D1/ex08/ex08)

I wish you the best.